Stubborn Spout Diverter not coming out
I have a 12 year old Shower Spout which leaks a bit when diverter is switched to Shower. So I bought Spout Diverter Replacement kit from Home Depot but my existing diverter is not coming out. I tried everything from Plier, Nose Plier, Screwdriver. I don't want to put too much pressure on it with the fear of breaking spout/pipe in the wall. What are my options?


I have tried to do the same replacement of the diverter seal.  I am experienced with a boat load of tools.
After fussing with this "thing" for over and hour, I took it back to the store and purchased a new spout and changed the whole spout in 10 minutes.
My time was worth far more than the $18 difference in price of the parts.
Just change the entire spout.  You will thank yourself later.

Thanks, @RMDman! I came to the same conclusion after trying for an hour and with some scratches on my hand. I found a spout for $10 on Home Depot USA. Most probably I will buy that and replace.
